# virtual qualifier in derived class

Tags: c++

Does the virtual qualifier to a virtual function of base class, in the derived class makes any difference ?

```
class b
{
   public:
   virtual void foo(){}
};

class d : public b
{
  public:
  void foo(){ .... }
};
```

or

```
class d : public b
{
  public:
  virtual void foo(){ .... }
};
```

Is there any difference in these two declarations, apart from that it makes child of d make aware of virtuality of foo() ?

Comment: afaik, it makes a difference if something else derives from class d

Comment: @Kshitij: No, even then it doesn't make any difference. Once `foo` is virtual, its virtual forever, no matter how far you go from the base in the class-hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

It makes no difference. `foo` is virtual in all classes that derive from b (and their descendants).

From C++03 standard, §10.3.2:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name and same parameter list as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (**whether or not it is so declared**) and it overrides Base::vf.

Answer (score 2):

No difference - it's a virtual override either way.

It's a matter of style and has been definitively discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370976/c-style-prefixing-virtual-keyword-to-overridden-methods)

Answer (score 1):

It's better style to include the virtual keyword.  But it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

No difference.

Once `foo` is *virtual*, its *virtual* forever in the class-hierarchy, no matter how far you go from the base in the class-hierarchy.

But I prefer to write `virtual` even in overrridden functions, because it adds **readability** to the code, which matters a lot.

Comment: For extra safety C++11 adds some override keyword which you can specify, so the compiler checks for you that when overriding a virtual function, you did not make a mistake in the signature and overloaded it accidentally