# Why f2 in class B is overridden by f2 in class D

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I'm failing to understand how can a grandchild (D) override a hidden (by C::f2(A&) method (B::f2(A)).

Here is an example code:

```cpp
class B{
    public:
    virtual void f2(A a){cout<<"B::f2()"<<endl;}
};

class C:public B{
private:
    public:
    virtual void f2(A& a){cout<<"C::f2(A&)"<<endl;
    }

};

class D:public C{
    public:
    void f2(A a){cout<<"D::f2(A)"<<endl;}
};

int main(void)
{
    B* b = new D();
    A a2 = A();
    A &a = a2;
    b->f2(a); // prints D::f2 - should'nt it print B::f2??

    C* c = new D();
    c->f2(a); // prints C::f2 - as expected
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098054/virtual-qualifier-in-derived-class . `D::f2` is a virtual actually and overrides `B::f2`

Comment: But C::f2 hides B::f2.

Comment: No, it does not hide it.  What makes you think it hides it?

Comment: @MikeNakis [Yes, it does](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eba15b55256affc) (though [that is fixable](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02746f429240edd2) if you're so-inclined)

Comment: The rules for virtual function overrides simply don't look at visibility at all. (Or access: you can override a virtual private function of a base class too.) Not sure what other kind of "why" you're looking for.

Comment: @aschepler But lookup happens before virtual dispatch happens, so calling `b->f2` will not find any function that takes `A`, regardless of whether that function is overridden.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure. Lookup for `b->f2` finds `B::f2` and calls its final overrider which is `D::f2`. Lookup for `c->f2` finds `C::f2` which is its own final overrider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why f2 in class B is overridden by f2 in class D

Because `D::f2` has the same argument list. A function with same name and argument list overrides a virtual function in base, if such virtual function in base exists.

Whether the virtual function has been hidden by another function with same name in an intermediate base or not has no effect on this.

The rule from the standard (draft):

> [class.virtual]
>
> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` overrides `Base::vf`.

So, to conclude, `D::f2` overrides `B::f2`, because it has same argument list. It does not override `C::f2`, because the argument list is different.

Comment: The function is called on a `B*`.

Comment: `The function is called on a B*` Indeed. And the dynamic type of the pointed object is `D`.

Comment: Oh yes. I got myself mixed up after proving that there _is_ hiding :D Kinda forgot the question after that..

Answer (score 2):

The interface of `B` does not have `f2( A& )`, so if the compiler was not to make an implicit conversion, your `b->f2( a );` would fail to compile.

But since the interface of `B` does have `f2( A )`, the compiler implicitly converts (*1) your `a` from type `A&` to type `A`.  So, the function of the form `f2( A )` is selected from the interface of `B`.

And since your `D` overrides that function, `D`'s function ends up being invoked.

(*1) C++ die-hards might know of a more specific term than 'implicitly converts' for precisely what happens in these cases.  But I am just an amateur.