# Should one declare functions virtual at all levels of inheritance or only at the ancestor level?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual

Should one mark explicitly as virtual all overrides in descendant classes at any level?

```
class Base {
// ...
protected:
  virtual void to_be_derived() const; // First level to introduce this virtual function
};

class LevelOne : public Base {
// ...
protected:
 // virtual??
 void to_be_derived() const;
};

class LevelTwo : public levelOne {
// ...
protected:
 // virtual??
 void to_be_derived() const;
};
```

I didn't see the [Prefixing virtual keyword to overridden methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370976) which answers my question. In particular, one of the answers there was updated to reflect current usage with respect to c++11, especially the `override` keyword that I didn't know about!

EDIT: I'd rather accept another answer from the linked question for post-c++11 code.

Comment: will be virtual by default in dervied class, so add virtual suffix or not, function will be virtual

Comment: Note that even the (correct) answer of using `override`/`final` already appears in the above question.

Comment: @jonezq I know the function would still be virtual but I see it as a way to *explicitly* convey to the class user that it is virtual.

Comment: As others have answered - better use new c++11 feature override and final, will give you compilation error, if it doesn't override any base virtual function

Comment: @jonezq I wanted to clarify why I wanted to use the `virtual` prefix in reply to your comment about the overridden function being already virtual, which I knew. Now, I didn't know about those new c++11 keywords but `override` is indeed the way to go for post c++11 code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowadays, it's better to mark them as `override`. It tells the reader the function is virtual, and is also a fail-safe mechanism (in case you get the signature wrong).

I'd only use `virtual` if that was consistent with already existing code.

```
class LevelOne : public Base {
protected:
   void to_be_derived() const override;
   //                            |
   // clearly virtual, certain it's the same signature as the base class
};
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `override` keyword. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: Just to be clear, the first occurrence of `to_be_derived` still needs to be `virtual` without the `override` keyword?

Comment: @greendiod in fact, if you use override and the base version isn't virtual, you'll get an error.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to mark them as virtual and override. Virtual will prevent you from calling wrong function for delivered object.  And override will prevent you from mistakes in signature and will make code more readable. 
As Scott Meyers wrote in effective c++ book, you should't redefine in delevired classes non virtual functions.

Comment: How does virtual *prevent you from calling wrong function*?

Comment: I meant that if someone declare to_be_derived() non virtual in LevelOne and LevelTwo classes and write something like LevelOne * p1 = new LewelTwo; p1->to_be_derived(); Wrong function would be called.

Comment: You cannot declare be_derived to be non virtual in LevelOne because it's virtual in Base.

Comment: @AndreyNekrasov So you'd still declare them all as `virtual` **plus** `override`?

Answer (score -2):

Base Class Virtual would force the inheriting class ie LevelOne to override it.

Unless you need LevelTwo to override LevelOne's implementation , you do not need to mark it as virtual.

In general, unless the derived class has to override it, no need of using virtual

Comment: "Unless you need LevelTwo to override LevelOne's implementation , you do not need to mark it as virtual." ???

Comment: Base class virtual does not force the inheriting class to override it. Also, if the function is virtual in base class, then you don't need to declare it virtual in the middle derived class in order to override in the most derived class.